# Can you put a Rod of the Pact Keeper or All-Purpose Tool into a Wand Sheath?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, warforged

Is it possible to put objects that are roughly in the same dimension and serve the same purpose as a wand into [Wand Sheathes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/215700-wand-sheath)? Things like Rods, All-Purpose Tools, Sprig of Mistletoe, Holy Symbols, flutes, etc?

Answer (score 6):

### You can only insert a wand

The Wand Sheath common magic item from *Eberron - Rising form the Last War* states:

> - You can **insert a wand** into the sheath as an action. The sheath can **hold only one wand** at a time.
> - You can retract or extend a wand from the sheath as a bonus action. While the wand is extended, you can use it as if you were holding it, but your hand remains free.

It only allows you to instert a wand, and it can only hold a wand. It would need to say so, if it allowed you to insert -- or use without requiring your hand -- something else. The idea behind this way to read the rules is often referred to as ["There are no secret rules"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196993/what-is-the-source-of-the-there-are-no-hidden-secret-rules-principle), and in particular for magic, where we cannot rely on our everyday experience to understand how it would work as ["Spells only do what they say they do"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret) (and in extension, magic items, too).

That's the written rules. It's up to your DM to allow you putting in other roughly wand-shaped items and overrule the rules, based on their assessment how fun and balanced that would be.